# Display error messages when submitting an object for approval

Tags: lightning, approval-process, error-messages

we have some validation rules that disallow an object to have certain status.
When we submit the object for approval, the status in changed.
So in the background the validation rule is triggered preventing the object to change the status, but the user does not receive any warning.

Is there any way to display validation error messages when submitting an object for approval in Lighting? (in classic it works fine).

Thanks